# How do I change the mode of all modals to ios in Ionic (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I change the mode of all my modals in my Ionic 5 application to be shown in the iOS modal-style?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change [mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/config#:%7E:text=the%20default%20%22animation%22.-,mode,-Mode) in config for `IonicModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot({
        ...
        mode: "ios",
        ... 
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```